# Missing row/column when plotting a surface in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Have a look at the following MATLAB code and the resulting surface plot. Maybe I am doing a stupid mistake, but there is actually a row and column missing. The variable z is a 10x10 matrix, but the plot shows only 9x9 elements. How to plot the whole 10x10 matrix?

```
z = randn(10,10);
t = 1:10;
x = 1:10;
figure;
surf(t,x,abs(z),'EdgeColor','none');   
axis xy; axis tight; colormap(jet); view(0,90);
```

[image]

Comment: There are 10 points in each direction, which accounts for 9 squares in each direction. Simplify this to 2 points in each direction to understand it better.

Comment: So I would need two vectors for both axes with a length of 11, in order to show all 10 squares, correct? But then MATLAB throws an error.

Comment: Matlab does not throw an error  because of the number 11. Specify.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what the hidden question is. Do you want: `surf(t,x,abs(z),'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','interp');` ?

Comment: Yes it does:
Error using surf (line xx)
Data dimensions must agree.

Try the code and enter 1:11 instead of 1:10 for both vectors.

Comment: If you replace the 10 by 11 in `z`, `t` and `x` there is no error.... Of course, if you try to plot more data in `z` than what there is in `x`, it errors... Note, in surf, you plot points, not squares. Points that for visualization, are connected via squares. Perhaps you want `imagesc(abs(z))`?

Comment: Sure, if I extend all dimensions to 11 it works .. I am not sure if you see my point: I want a surface plot where the whole z-matrix is shown, so 10x10. But the surface shows only 9x9! How do I adjust the code for that?

Comment: Read the edit on my last comment

Comment: Yes, imagesc is what I am looking for it seems, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a misunderstanding about what surf does, i.e. what a surface plot is:

What you seem to be wanting is an actual image instead of a surface plot, where for the former pixels correspond to the underlying values. What you get with surf is a graphical representation of lines at a certain height (abs(z) in your case), i.e. between your desired image pixels. Note that there are 10x10 lines in your 9x9 plot.

What you want can be achieved visually e.g. by:

```
z = randn(10,10);
t = 1:10;
x = 1:10;

figure
imshow(abs(z),[]), 
axis on, colormap(gca,jet)
colorbar
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice answer. You can also use `imagesc(abs(z))` instead of `imshow` to get a larger image, similar to what `surf` would do. Edit: I see Ander Biguri already commented that